# Publishing visitor posts through Graph API as a Facebook Page admin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

As a Facebook Page admin, I want to be able to publish a visitor's post through the Graph API. The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/post/) on Facebook's developer's portal explicitly states that the `is_hidden` field is not valid for approving a visitor's post on a Page. Is there another Graph API endpoint that I can accomplish this with?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for _moderation_ on posts people have made on your page, rather than actually _making_ the post itself …?

Comment: That's correct - I wish to moderate on posts people have made on my page.

Comment: Apps can only edit posts that were created via that very same app - so if users post onto your page by any other means than your app, you can't do anything via API here.